# Programmatically change the value of a field without entering editmode and still refresh form

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

In my Lotus Notes application (classic, not using XPages), the user won't be able to edit documents directly.

Instead, modifications will happen dialog-based and triggered through actions on the form.

For example, I have an action invoking code similar to the following:

```
Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
Dim result As String
Dim document As NotesDocument
Dim options(1 To 6) As String

'... - Fill options

Set document = ws.CurrentDocument.Document
result = ws.Prompt(PROMPT_OKCANCELCOMBO, "New Value", "Please choose the new value", document.Foo(0), options)

If result <> "" Then
    document.Foo = result

    Call document.ComputeWithForm(False, True)
    Call document.Save(True, False)
End If
```

This updates the value of `Foo` to the value the user chose in the dialog.

However, this new value is not shown to the user - the Form does not seem to be refreshed.
Reopening and closing the form does show the new value; it definitely gets updated.

The nearest I could get was the following code (inside the if-block):

```
ws.CurrentDocument.EditMode = True
document.Foo = result
Call ws.CurrentDocument.Save()
ws.CurrentDocument.EditMode = False
```

Nevertheless, this solution seems a bit suboptimal to me as I have to enter edit mode.

How can I refresh the form using Notes Script to reflect the change of the field without having to enter edit-mode?
Methods like `ws.CurrentDocument.Refresh` either don't show any effect or raise errors as they can't be used outside edit-mode.

Many thanks in advance for your ideas, tips and solutions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found another solution avoiding entering edit-mode:

As the documentation to `Reload` states:

> Modifications made to the back-end document outside the current
>   editing session (for example, by an agent or another user) do not
>   appear until the document is closed and reopened. You can close and
>   reopen a front-end document with `NotesUIDocument.Close(True)` and
>   `NotesUIWorkspace.EditDocument`.

Thus, the document can be "refreshed" (with a bit of flickering) using:

```
Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
Dim document As NotesDocument
Set document = ws.CurrentDocument.Document
'...
Call ws.Currentdocument.Close(True)
Call ws.Editdocument(False, document)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is the best one. Going into edit mode and either setting the field and saving or simply refreshing the page after you've already set the field is the right idea. It's unfortunate but necessary.

The user will need edit rights to the document of course which presents another problem.  How do you prevent the user from typing control E or clicking a smart icon to edit the document?

For that you can set a Global variable that controls access to editing the document.  When you're opening your dialog you can set that global variable to true and then set it back to false after you've made your changes.  In the query mode changed event set continue to the value of that global variable.

Comment: Thanks! It seems that when writing Lotus Notes applications, developing workaround takes most of the time... ;-)

Comment: You can say that again! :)  Heck, that's why I like answering questions here.  All those hours/days/weeks I spent figuring out workarounds can hopefully save someone else some time.

Answer (score 1):

If your user has editor rights in that document, you are not able to stop him to bypass any script action in your form and simply edit it.

Better way to let user edit only particular fields is Controlled Access Section.

Comment: Ken Pespisa's workaround of setting "Continue" to false in QueryModeChange seems to work to prevent direct editing. When using the CAS: Wouldn't that mean that scripts won't be able to change the fields, too if invoked by the user?

Comment: First of all, Continue=false in QueryModeChange is not enough. Try open document from view using Ctrl+E. You have to check the mode in QueryOpen event, too.
Second, what if there is a view, where those documents opens via different form? Where is your script action now?
At last, but not least, there is a user access model, driven by ACL and readers/authors fields. Will you grant Editor access to whole application?

Comment: Your solution is just a dummy workaround like set user password in SQL database and ignore real db access politics. Better way is to design your forms in the proper way. What is to be edited, should be edited in separate form. If you need to let users edit documents via main form, use rather CAS, or better - create some request mechanism and let server do the job in scheduled agent.

Comment: "What is to be edited, should be edited in separate form" - that's exactly what I am trying to achieve with my dialog-based solution. My question is about getting the data back from the dialog specific document into the original one.

Comment: DialogBox is not a form. I didn't see your applicatoin, so I cannot say, how exactly it looks like, but I would rather grant an Author access for users in ACL and use response documents with Authors field. Then you can simply display those response documents in an Embedded view, or better use xPages. Or use scheduled agent to do the edit job in the main document based on the value in reponse. All of it depends on how safe your application should be. If safety doesn't realy matter, script action is good, CAS is better. If it does matter, you'd better rethink your application architecture.

Comment: The application will be used internally only. The users of the application will be readers / editors in the ACL. However, I can trust editors not to abuse their "power". The deactivation of the edit mode should mainly hinder them to accidentally edit fields causing inconsistent data. On the other hand, the dialog-based mechanism does additional validation and ensures that certain modifications only occur when documents are in certain states. Therefore, the restrictions are not in place because of security considerations but for enforcing data input according to business processes.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a table. You want to show the next row to add an order item or something:

```
@setfield("NumOrders";NumOrders+1);
@Command( [ViewRefreshFields] )
```

You need a hidden field `NumOrders`, then refresh will work.

```
@Command( [ViewRefreshFields] )
```

It's that easy!